# js mac overwrite keyboard shortcut

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, keyevent

default Mac keyboard shortcut in safari, I want to overwrite them. such as `cmd+s`, `cmd+n`

```js
let isMeta = false;
    window.onkeydown = e => {
        if(e.key == "Meta"){
            isMeta = true;
        }else if(e.key == 's' && isMeta){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('s');
        }else if(e.key == 'n' && isMeta){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('n');
        }
    };
    window.onkeyup = e => {
        if(e.key == "Meta"){
            isMeta = false;
        }
    };
```

testing result: `cmd+s` succeeded, when I press the shortcut, saving action is prevented and `s` is logged. but `ctrl+n` will call default opening new tab and `n` is not logged.

I wonder why this happens, why one works but the other.

Comment: I'm not sure cmd+n is sent to the page

Comment: I'm pretty sure some of them can't be overwritten, as it would allow you to overwrite common behaviour like closing windows etc...

Comment: cheers for all helps above, may I ask can I use ctrl instead? is windows the same? I have tried `option` and it seems not working as well, Mac defines them with unicode insertion.